# PHP concatenate html php code

Tags: php, escaping, concatenation

What am I doing wrong¿?

```
echo "<img src= 'vestido'.$id.'.jpg' height=500 width=500 >";
```

I dont know how to concatenate this correctly.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basic PHP: If you start a string with one type of quotes e.g. `"`, you have to END the string with the same type of quotes. PHP is not recursively executable, nor will PHP look inside strings for PHP operators, like concatenation `.`'s.

You have:

```
echo "<img src= 'vestido'.$id.'.jpg' height=500 width=500 >";
     ^---start of string                                   ^--end of string
```

when it should be

```
echo "<img src= 'vestido" . $id . ".jpg' height=500 width=500 >";
     ^--start           ^--stop   ^---start                    ^--stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing " and '

With " for simple variables you do not need to concat

For ' you have done it correct either replace the start and end " with ' or remove the concat

Answer (score 1):

You are opening your string with a double quote and attempting to close (in order to add a variable) with a single quote. This is not required as you can put variables directly into double quoted strings;

```
echo "<img src= 'vestido{$id}.jpg' height='500' width='500' >";
```

In this case I've added curly brackets around the variable to make this obvious. You might need to do this if your variable is immediately followed by a character that is valid in a variable (such as a number or letter) rather than one that isn't (such as a space, hyphen, or dot).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert `$id` within the echo

```
<?php
$id=5;

echo "<img src= 'vestido$id.jpg' height=500 width=500 >";
?>
```

will yield `<img src= 'vestido5.jpg' height=500 width=500 >`

Based on your code it looked like you wanted to do `echo "<img src= 'vestido" . $id . ".jpg' height=500 width=500 >";` which would work as well